# Entity Framework - One application/One user/One simple use case ... seem simple but is not

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a simple time sheet application. It manages:

- Group of employees
- Employees
- A list of WorkEntry for each Employee

The use case is the following:

1. My user start the application and connect to a database.
2. He looks at his WorkEntry for the day.
3. He adds 2 new WorkEntries, but is **NOT** saving the data right now.
4. He prints the WorkEntries, a dialog is showing him the progression of the operation which can take some time to complete.

---

When I first started the application, I had a single ObjectContext created at the connection (in the UI thread) and disposed when the user closed the application.

It was working quite well, but I faced a problem implementing the printing function because I was not able to use the ObjectContext in a background worker thread.

Googling a little bit I found the concept of unit of work.

- Create the ObjectContext
- Do want you want to do
- Close it

Also, my understanding is that entities are belonging to one ObjectContext.

Let say ObjectContext#1
 - Is used in the UI thread to retreive WorkEntries for the day
 - Contains the two new WorkEntries of the user.
 - Is not yet disposed because the user has not saved his changes

Let say ObjectContext#2
 - Is used in the background worker thread
 - Retreive WorkEntries for the day
 - Print the WorkEntries

How can ObjectContext#2 be aware of the two new WorkEntries in ObjectContext#1?

---

**EDIT**

I know there is a flaw ... the user MUST save to get the two new entries in the printed report.

But let say my application is presenting the data in a grid, like excel. The user will expect (*with good reasons*) the same behavior has excel. That is, in excel, I'm not forced to save to print my new rows ... I just want to print what I see on my sheet, no matter the persistence state of the data presented.

Comment: I think there is a design flaw here; what if the worker adds two new WorkEntries and print out but does not save? IMHO, you should first force saving the data then enable printing.

Comment: You are right, there is a flaw ... but I don't want to force saving data to allow the user to print it, the user just want to print what he sees, no matter the persistance state.  Let say I'm showing my data in a grid (like excel). Does excel force you to save before printing? Non, it just prints what you see on the screen.

Comment: Yes, but excel prints what it sees. If you have a shared excel spreadsheet and you are not connected to the network and hit print, then it just prints what it has in memory, not what might be out on the network. You can either print what is currently displayed to the user, what is only in the database, or both combined....however if you use the combined approach, then you must create a hybrid of getting the current database state, making sure it is synced (what if the user was doing a conflicting update), and then add on the in-memory items....personally, I would say just go with the in-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading this right, then you are thinking about this wrong. The flow should go something like this (pseudo code)

User requests data:

```
Open a context
Retrieve data
Close the context
```

User saves data:

```
Open a context
Save the data
Close the context
```

Print work entries:

```
Open a context
Retrieve the data
Close the context
Print the data
```

Notice that in all of these, the context is only open as long as it is needed to perform the appropriate database action. If the print occurs before the user saves their changes, then the changes will not be printed since they have not been persisted by the user anyway.

**NOW**, sometimes there is a valid approach to keeping the context open throughout the lifetime of the application. However, the same rule should still apply. If the user saves the data, then the other context will become aware of it immediately anyway, as it will pull fresh data from the database when asked to print. Again, if the user does not save their changes, then it is not in the database, so it will not be printed. What if we print it and the user decides to discard the changes? If you want to avoid that situation, then you should probably prompt the user that printing will not pick up the unsaved data and allow them to choose if they still want to print or save the data. If you want to allow them to print saved AND unsaved data, then that is a different problem than EF contexts

Comment: If I understand the pseudo code, if the user want to print all the data, including its 2 new WorkEntries, he has to save it before doing so?

Comment: @Nicolas yes, in fact, I just added a couple of lines at the end of my answer to cover that. Basically, if you want an "if I save" type of print, then that is a different design and not an EF problem. EF is just an ORM to talk to the DB, not to DB AND in-memory.

Comment: I understand, but ... what if my application presents the data in a grid, like excel. In excel, I can add a row, print and save later or event delete the row I added and it's ok. The user prints what he is seeing, not matter if its persisted or not

Comment: @Nicolas Then, again, that is a different design. You are printing what the user is seeing, not what is in the database. Your print should be pulling from your grid, not the EF based back-end

Comment: I understand, but the printing is just an example ... there can be situations where not all the data is shown and I'm afraid that I will have to build a layer on top of EF ... to manage that.

Comment: @Nicolas Yup, that about sums that up. If you want database and memory, then that is a different problem and will require that top layer. I do not know of any extensions that would help here either :(

Answer (score 0):

Create #2 just when you are about to start printing (not when the app starts).  It will query the backing datastore and have the latest data for that point in time.

Comment: But, if my understanding of EF is right, I have to force to user to save the new entries before printing so that the #2 can have all the latest data ...

Answer (score 0):

You can just create your context when you need it and then dispose it.

A common approach is like the following

```
using(YourContext context = new YourContext)
{
 // Do stuff here
 // and then when you pass the using block context is disposed so you can reuse it
}
```